# Disable cell broadcast notifications on Lenovo A 7000

Tags: lenovo, cell-broadcast

I am receiving more than 100 notification alerts for cell broadcast on my Lenovo A7000 with Android Lollipop. I did not found any settings for cell broadcast.

Can anyone please help me in disabling this to stop these alerts?

Comment: As suggested elsewhere [Android Lollipop Disable cell broadcast messages – solution ]( http://www.solvemix.com/index.php/android-smartphones/423-android-lollipop-disable-cell-broadcast-messages-solution)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you checked the [other questions tagged `cell-broadcast`](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell-broadcast)? Does none of those solutions work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Message Setting -> Cell Broadcast-> Select Provide -> Uncheck the "ETWS Alert".